# Horizontal and Vertical ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Do anyone have successfully implemented ViewPager which scrolls Horizontally and Vertically?

I know [Directional ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager),When i use it it gives

```
<i>31 12:11:29.954: E/AndroidRuntime(14670): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager$DataSetObserver
10-31 12:11:29.954: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager.setAdapter(DirectionalViewPager.java:164)</i>
```

line no 164:**mObserver = new DataSetObserver();**

```
public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        VerticalViewPagerCompat.setDataSetObserver(mAdapter, null);
    }

    mAdapter = adapter;

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        if (mObserver == null) {
            mObserver = new DataSetObserver();
        }
        VerticalViewPagerCompat.setDataSetObserver(mAdapter, mObserver);
        mPopulatePending = false;
        if (mRestoredCurItem >= 0) {
            mAdapter.restoreState(mRestoredAdapterState, mRestoredClassLoader);
            setCurrentItemInternal(mRestoredCurItem, false, true);
            mRestoredCurItem = -1;
            mRestoredAdapterState = null;
            mRestoredClassLoader = null;
        } else {
            populate();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: what is line 164 in DirectionaViewPager.java?

Answer (score 0):

I found your answer You just add the DirectionalViewPager as a library into your project

[image: Add this image as an external library]

This libray is located at **Android-DirectionalViewPager-master\Android-DirectionalViewPager-master\library\bin**

and ya dont forget to include it from order and export tab